# Using RegEx to add dynamic code to class files

Tags: c#, regex, string, streamreader, streamwriter

I basically want to know how to write a simple program that will parse all of the class files in a folder and makes some changes. Specifically, I need to take a class file that looks like:

```
public class Something {

//somecode

}
```

And make it so that it looks like this:

```
public class Something {

public static CollectionBase<Something> GetAll() {
return new CollectionBase<Something>(DataLayer.Something.GetAll());

//somecode

}
```

And I basically have to do this on about 200 files (amongst a few other modifications, but if I can do the above I can tailor it to solve the other changes too).

I'm not super familiar with c# but I think in pseudo code it will probably be something like the following:

1. Open each .cs file in a folder
2. Read each line until it finds a regex match for: "public class Something"
3. Put the match of "Something" in a string like tempS
4. Insert some new lines below it, like: "public static CollectionBase<" + tempS + "> GetAll()"
5. Then write the new file to a new folder.

   Any suggestions on how to write something like this would be greatly appreciated. I've only been learning C# for about 3-4 months and it can be a bit overwhelming to syntactically digest all of the instructions people give each other. TIA! -Evan

EDIT: So, I'm sure any regex guru had this handled in seconds, but I'm going to post my solution here anyway, which was a simple Find and Replace regex string:

Find:
public class (\w*) : SimpleObjectBase {

Replace:
[NamedType("$1")]\r\n    public class $1 : SimpleObjectBase, ICCPSystemType {\r\n\r\n        #region Static\r\n\r\n        public static CollectionBase GetAll() {\r\n            return new CollectionBase(CCP.Data.$1.GetAll());\r\n        }\r\n\r\n        #endregion

And here is an example of it's work:

Before--
namespace CCP.Logic {

```
///<summary>
///This class represents each TypeBabySexByULS in the database
///</summary>
[NamedType("TypeBabySexByULS")]
public class TypeBabySexByULS : SimpleObjectBase {
```

...///onto other code

After--
namespace CCP.Logic {

```
///<summary>
///This class represents each TypeBabySexByULS in the database
///</summary>
[NamedType("TypeBabySexByULS")]
public class TypeBabySexByULS : SimpleObjectBase, ICCPSystemType {

    #region Static

    public static CollectionBase<TypeBabySexByULS> GetAll() {
        return new CollectionBase<TypeBabySexByULS>(CCP.Data.TypeBabySexByULS.GetAll());
    }

    #endregion
```

///  Hopefully that can help someone else! -E

Comment: I'd suggest using Visual Studio's Regular Expression Replace. In your Solution Window, filter the view to show only the files. Open the Find All windows (Ctrl + Shift + F if I remember right). Filter your search by *.cs file extension and Create your Regex to match all occurences in the scope of your filtered solution view's CS file. For more information on Visual Studio Regular Expression, Capture group and how to access them in the Replace Window, See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2k3te2cs.aspx

Comment: If you need to change 200 files to implement something, you might have a more fundamental design problem. Have you considered a solution via one of the well-established design patterns?

Comment: Best to do this using Templates, eg T4.

Comment: DataLayer is another project in the solution that holds all of the corresponding class files that do Data Access. Currently, I'm trying to modify the class files in the Business Logic Layer.

I am trying to figure out how to use capture groups to get the match into a string so I can do my pseudo steps now, having a hard time figuring it out :(   I'll take a look into Templates (T4) since I have no idea what you're referring to. 

This all essentially came about because the person I work for created the database first, then use a code gen. utility to make all of the classes.

Comment: I'm with itsme86. Rather than adding the same static method to a lot of classes, try a single generic static method on one data layer class.

Comment: If you're marshaling DataLayer objects up through  business layer types, your return types are a bit wonky.   Should BusinessLayer.Something.GetAll() return a collection of BusinessLayer.Something or DataLayer.Something?

Comment: okay, so all of my classes I need to change do derive from SimpleObjectBase, so if I were to go in there and add this method, how would I make it so each inherited class created it's collection of it's own type? like:

    public virtual CollectionBase<This> GetAll() {
    return new CollectionBase<This>(CCP.Data.This.GetAll());
        }

Comment: and Patrick, essentially the DataLayer has the SQL statements to get a DataTable, and the BusinessLayer doesn't do anything in this scenario. I don't see any advantage of this except a separation of concerns...

Comment: So DataLayer is a .. ? namespace?

Comment: yes, I have CCP.Data , CCP.Logic , and CCP.Web (which has viewmodels for any objects going to controllers) -- And CollectionBase is a custom class from CCP.Logic.Collections

Comment: Seems that I don't get your idea of design .. sorry for unable to help. I'll later back to see if someone answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do "Metaprogramming".
First of all you should carefully examine if generics are solving your problem. If you are literally just extracting class names, then the clean solution should be generics.
For T4 templates, I would recommend to look at the "Introducing T4 templates" example from [Meta Programming in .NET](http://www.manning.com/hazzard/) and then ask specific questions.